# How to hide a ProgressBar in AsyncTask programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have the following static `AsyncTask` class:

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do heavy stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        super.onPostExecute(string);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I want to show/hide the `progressBar` as you see in those two methods. The problem is that I have to make the `progressBar` static. Doing this, I get:

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

If I remove the static that stays in front of my `MyAsyncTask` class I get:

> This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (MainActivity.MyAsyncTask)

How to solve this?

**Edit:**

```
private void checkUser() {
    uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            User user = document.toObject(User.class);
            if (user == null) {
                MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
                myAsyncTask.execute(url);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The class MyAsyncTask doesn't need to be static if you are calling only from MainActivity.

Comment: How are you sending the String output back to Main class/activity?

Comment: @myatmins I create a new object `MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();` only from a method within the `MainActivity`, why do you say that it doesn't need to be static?

Comment: @amitava Just setting the value on a `TextVIew`, that's it. How to solve this?

Comment: Please also show the code where you execute the async task.

Comment: @amitava Just added, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this "static" problem in async task earlier and there is a really nice way to get the output of async task back to activity . Simply put

```
String output = myAsyncTask.execute(url).get();
```

You will get the output, The final code is.

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                  
String output = myAsyncTask.execute(url).get();
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Until you get the output the next line will not be executed.  I am adding an example code for further demo.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button exe = findViewById(R.id.async);
    exe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                updateAsyncTask up = new updateAsyncTask();

                long l = up.execute().get();
                System.out.println("inside main "+l);                    
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}

 private static class updateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        long l = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
        {
            l = l+i;
            System.out.println(l);              

        }
        return l;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks and where should I set `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` now? Because in my code I'm setting it in `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: As I stated you can set it on just before myAsyncTask.execute(url). Will that be a problem?

Comment: Are you sure that calling `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` right after `String output = myAsyncTask.execute(url).get();` it waits for the job inside `doInBackground` to be done?

Comment: That is what I remember because I used the output as return, if no output was returned I would have gotten a null pointer exception.

Comment: Let's me try and get you back.

Comment: It seems it doesn't wait. This solution it's a guess or are you sure? Have you try it?

Comment: I just rechecked it and it is working as intended. I have added an example code in my answer. If you run it you will see the printout after .execute, i.e. System.out.println("inside main "+l);  is coming only after the for loop execution inside async task.

Comment: Let me check again. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, it waits for the job inside the `doInBackground` to be done. Thank you!

Comment: @IoanaP. Yes it will , but that is what I already informed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for using asyncTask as a static subclass and for solving it I used method reflection. this might be a little tricky but it works for me:

```
public class MainClass{
 @keep
 public void AfterLoad(String value) {

  }
 public void callAsync() {
   Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[1];
    parameterTypes[0] = String.class;
    try {
        Method method1 = MainClass.class.getMethod("AfterLoad", 
  parameterTypes);
        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this, method1);
        task.execute(link);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private final Method mAfterLoad;
    private final Object mOwner;

    public MyAsyncTask(Object owner, Method afterLoad) {
        this.mAfterLoad = afterLoad;
        this.mOwner = owner;
    }  
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... requests) {
     // do what you want
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (mAfterLoad != null) {
            try {
                Object[] parameters = new Object[1];
                parameters[0] = values[0];
                mAfterLoad.invoke(mOwner, parameters);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

by doing so you will overcome the memory leak issue, however, note that for calling the method, the name of it is passed as a string and you should add @keep annotation for  saving it from pro-guard optimization and refactoring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try and get you back.